# How to run the code in the active tab in PyCharm?

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, pycharm

I know it is not that cleaver question, however I am pretty new to PyCharm and Python.

So as the question tells, I would like to make a shortcut to run the code in the active tab without going to the window "Edit Configurations" and change the running script manually.

I use OS 10.9.1, PyCharm edition 3.0.2

Comment: Right click on the source file, "Run this" (play icon). A new shortcut will be added to the combo box in the toolbar.

Comment: Shortcut: shift + control + F10. It creates a run configuration. Then you just press the play button in the top bar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply right click and run:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for being so late but I was having the same problem. Maybe will help others in the future.

What you seek is the **Run Context Configuration** option which will run your current active tab.

In PyCharm version 2021.2.1 (should be the same in all versions) go to:

**File** --> **Settings** --> **Keymap** --> **Run Context Configuration** --> Right Click --> Add Keyboard Shortcut.

The screenshot bellow will help you more.

[image: PyCharm snapshot]

Comment: As of version PyCharm 2023.2 (Professional Edition) this option allows me to run the tab which has focus

Answer (score -1):

Go "Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Python Interpreter" and add your interpreter (the green '+' at up right corner of "settings" windows).

Then, already will available the green Play button (together the 'bug' icon) to run your project from Pycharm.

Answer (score -1):

For MacOS (10.5 keymap):

Ctrl + Shift + R

[image]

Not sure why the windows answer was accepted...